# Sublime Text 3 Build System run /dev/build in SilverStripe

Tags: sublimetext3, silverstripe, build-system

I'm looking answer is it possible to create build system in `sublime text 3` which will run `/dev/build` on `SilverStripe project`. Is it possible to create `build system` which will run url eg.

```
 http://mysite.local/dev/build
```

It could be even greater if I will get response in sublime console or so.

Anyone can help?

Comment: yes it possible to create a built system using sublime text 3 .. i cunt tell you the entire package structure but i have create a built system for Postgresql for sublime text 3.

Comment: I don't know about the build system of sublime text. but it enough if it can execute a command. SilverStripe has a commandline interface as well, you can run a dev build via `sake dev/build`. However, this obviously has to be executed on the machine that runs the website. more about SilverStripe from the commandline line: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/commandline

Comment: Would be great to interact with local dev server. If you figure something out, I'd love to include in in my [SilverStripe Sublime package](https://github.com/benjamin-smith/sublime-text-silverstripe) or at least link to it. More inspiration [can be found on SS Bits](http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2012/silverstripe-developer-bookmarklets/), using bookmarklets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. If you save your project `Project -> Save project` in the same directory as your silverstripe installation. Make sure to switch Project to the one you just made (not sure if it does it automatically. You need to make a new build system `Tools -> Build System -> New Build System` and use this code:

```
{
   "shell_cmd": "php ${project_path:${folder}}/framework/cli-script.php dev/build"
}
```

remember to choose your new Build System in the same menu.

Now you can execute your build with cmd+b or f7, depending on how your key bindings are set up.